# Randomly combine pandas group objects

Tags: python, pandas

**Question:**

How can one use pandas df.groupby() function to create randomly selected groups of groups?

**Example:**

I would like to group a dataframe into random groups of size n where n corresponds to the number of unique values in a given column.

I have a dataframe with a variety of columns including "id".  Some rows have unique ids whereas others may have the same id.  For example:

```
   c1 id c2
0   a  1  4
1   b  2  6
2   c  2  2
3   d  5  7 
4   y  9  3
```

In reality this dataframe can have up to 1000 or so rows.

I would like to be able to group this dataframe using the following criteria:

- each group should contain at most n unique ids
- no id should appear in more than one group
- the specific ids in a given group should be selected randomly
- each id should appear in exactly one group

For example the example dataframe (above) could become:

group1:

```
   c1 id c2
0   a  1  4
4   y  9  3
```

group2:

```
   c1 id c2
1   b  2  6
2   c  2  2
3   d  5  7
```

where n = 2

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems difficult for a uniq `groupby` statement. A way to do that :

```
uniq=df['id'].unique()
random.shuffle(uniq)
groups=np.split(uniq,2)
dfr=df.set_index(df['id'])

for gp in groups : print (dfr.loc[gp])
```

For

```
   c1  id  c2
id           
9   y   9   3
1   a   1   4

   c1  id  c2
id           
5   d   5   7
2   b   2   6
2   c   2   2
```

If size of groups(`n`) does'nt divide `len(uniq)`, You can use `np.split(uniq,range(n,len(uniq),n))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':list('abcdy'), 'id':[1,2,2,5,9], 'c2':[4,6,2,7,3]})

n = 2
shuffled_ids = np.random.permutation(df['id'].unique())
id_groups  = [shuffled_ids[i:i+n] for i in xrange(0, len(shuffled_ids), n)]
groups = [df['id'].apply(lambda x: x in g) for g in id_groups]
```

Output:

```
In [1]: df[groups[0]]
Out[1]:
  c1  c2  id
1  b   6   2
2  c   2   2
3  d   7   5

In [2]: df[groups[1]]
Out[2]:
  c1  c2  id
0  a   4   1
4  y   3   9
```

This approach doesn't involve changing the index, in case you need to keep it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It does the job very well.  I ended up going with B.M.'s answer below as the accepted one only because it is faster. If I could accept yours as well I would.

Comment: That's because the other answer is modifying the index of the dataframe. In case that's acceptable, you can just ignore `groups` and index straight by `id_groups` after changing the index (i.e. `df2 = df.set_index('id')`, `df2.ix[id_groups[0]]`). That will probably solve the performance issue.